# First attempts to C, problems with header

Tags: c

This is kind of my first C code.

I basically have a main Program which includes an header, in this header a function is defined, and in the header.c file this function is written, and in the my main Program file the function is used. I also got an Make file

I hope I got this right in terms of factoring.

I get this cryptic error, which I don't really understand, so I hope you could help out. Maybe I got something with the linking wrong in the make file?

```
jakob@linux-hkem:~/Studium/Sem5/Betriebssysteme/Task1A> make all
cc     header.c   -o header
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.17/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:119: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [header] Fehler 1
```

Here's my code:

**Make file:**

```
all: ispalindrom

ispalindrom: ispalindrom.c header
    gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE -o ispalindrom ispalindrom.c header.c

clean: rm -f ispalindrom
```

**Main program file (ispalindrom.c)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if((checkPalin("Jakob")) == 0){
        printf("%s ist ein Palindrom\n", "Jakob");
    }
    else {
        printf("%s ist kein Palindrom\n", "Jakob");
    }
    if((checkPalin("abcba")) == 0){
        printf("%s ist ein Palindrom\n", "abcba");
    }
    else {
        printf("%s ist kein Palindrom\n", "abcba");
    }
    if(checkPalin("abccba") == 0){
        printf("%s ist ein Palindrom\n", "abccba");
    }
    else {
        printf("%s ist kein Palindrom\n", "abccba");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**header.h**

```
/* header.h */
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

int checkPalin(char *);

#endif /* HEADER_H */
```

**header.c**

```
#include "header.h"
#include <string.h>

/**
* return 0 when String is an palindrom.
*/
int checkPalin(char string[]) {
    int start  = 0;
    int end    = strlen(string);
    while(start < end) {
        if(string[start] != string[end]) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ispalindrom: ispalindrom.c header` should be `ispalindrom: ispalindrom.c header.c` since it looks for header.c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to run:

```
cc -c header.c
cc -c ispalindrom.c
cc -o ispalindrom ispalindrom.o header.o
```

Or:

```
cc -o ispalindrom ispalindrom.c header.c
```

You can add other compiler options if necessary (optimizer flags, etc).  Indeed, it would be good to compile with `-Wall` (or, more stringently, `-Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes`, or similar).

Actually, there's a buglet in your `makefile`; you say that `ispalindrom` depends on `header`.

You need:

```
all: ispalindrom

ispalindrom: ispalindrom.c header.c
    gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE -o ispalindrom ispalindrom.c header.c

clean:
    rm -f ispalindrom
```

Or:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE

all: ispalindrom

ispalindrom: ispalindrom.o header.o

clean:
    rm -f ispalindrom header.o ispalindrom.o core a.out
```

Comment: thanx for the answer, but how is this different from my code in the make file? `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE -o ispalindrom ispalindrom.c header.c`

Comment: See updated answer — I missed the makefile buried in the middle on the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

gcc tries to compile header.c as the main application instead of as object file, searching for function main.
You should add -c compiler switch for header.c